# AttributeError: module 'test' has no attribute 'myfunc'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a class which in one of his functions is calling another function from another file that I made:

```
import test
class myclass:
    ...
    def mainfunc(self):
        test.myfunc()
    ...
start = myclass()
start.mainfunc()
```

But it gives me this error:

> AttributeError: module 'test' has no attribute 'myfunc'

And I don't know why it doesn't call it, even my editor in which I'm working it auto completes the function for me.

How can I fix this?

Comment: please provide some info for what `test` looks like

Answer (score 1):

The test module (https://docs.python.org/3/library/test.html#module-test) is used for internal python regression testing, It might be that you are importing that module, rather than your class with the same name.

Answer (score -1):

Simply change the import statement to

```
from test import myfunc
```

And inside `mainfunc` use

```
myfunc()
```

This solution assumes that there is a function `myfunc` inside `test`.

Comment: If there's no function `myfunc()` in the `test` module, how would `from test import myfunc` help at all?